# How to capture nullpointerexception,ftp connection issues via a log/output file talend job

Tags: java, exception, talend, jobs

[image]My talend job is working perfectly now,but i would like to induce some basic quality validation checks and put them in place to capture the error right away without any hassle.So inorder for that i am going to schedule the job to run hourly and if there is some failure due to **disk space,FTP connection failure issues,errors due to file parsing name(by splitting the name i will load into db)** -So if i run into  java **IOException****nullpointerexception** or something like that.How do i capture the error from console onto the log file in the folder from the talend job which keeps running in the background.

This is the code i am using to write the console output to an file.however i cannot capture the erraneous cases,please advise how to do that:

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:/Users/hsivakumar/Desktop/tests/output.txt");

java.io.PrintStream ps = new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream(file));

//java.io.File outputFileErr = new java.io.File("C:/Users/hsivakumar/Desktop/tests/outputerr.txt");

System.setOut(ps);

System.setErr(outputFileErr);
```

I am getting an error when using setErr

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to code in Talend to catch and log Exception. Just drop a tLogCatcher and link its output to a file component.

[image]

The tLogCatcher will catch the Exception and populate several fields.

[image]

The tFileOutputDelimited will create your log file.

[image]

Comment: I was using the same too,but for any file parsing error when i run into situations like "unparseeable data" when the file name is not in the right format,i was wondering if i would need to create a special try,catch exception block in my tjava code.But if the tlogcatcher handles all of them at once,i think i am good.